# Spring Boot Apache SSL Reverse Proxy

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, https, springframework

I have a Spring Boot application that runs on a Amazon Linux server. I use Apache HTTP server as a proxy server for this application. Recently I installed Let's Encrypt SSL certificate and added a virtual host entry on Apache for that. However, I cannot get it to work with Spring Boot properly. No SSL version seems to be working fine though.

What I observed is that the requests comes to the Spring Boot application when a user calls the https version of it, but user receives a HTTP 404 error from Apache. For example this works fine: http://example.com/oauth/token but this does not work and return 404: https://example.com/oauth/token

I posted the config files below, what am I missing?

**vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(/api/v1) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(/oauth/token) - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/example.com/cert/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/example.com/cert/privkey.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
    ProxyPass /api/v1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1
    ProxyPassReverse /api/v1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1
    ProxyPass /oauth/token http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/token
    ProxyPassReverse /oauth/token http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/token
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(/api/v1) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(/oauth/token) - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /api/v1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1
    ProxyPassReverse /api/v1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1
    ProxyPass /oauth/token http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/token
    ProxyPassReverse /oauth/token http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/token
</VirtualHost>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.context-path=/api/v1
server.address=127.0.0.1
server.port=8080
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

Comment: add "apachectl -S" output to your question. Make sure the output matches the virtualhosts you are showing here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be "server.tomcat.protocol-header" not "protocol**_**header"

Exampe:
`server.tomcat.protocol-header-https-value=https
server.tomcat.protocol-header=X-Forwarded-Proto
server.tomcat.port-header=X-Forwarded-Port`

Comment: These properties are not listed in spring-boot 2.4.9 docs, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.9/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

```
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for

server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

Reference Link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html